# php foreach outside the function

Tags: php, mysql

i'm learning php.

i have a function with mysql query select.

than i use it with foreach list..

but it work me only if the foreach is inside the function.
i don't know how to get it work outside the function..

what i'm doing wrong?

working code - https://phpbox.info/d3GCP

no working code:

```
function volaco ()
{
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query = "select a.id, count(i.id) as all_items, a.name,  SUM(i.state = '1') published, SUM(i.state = '0') unpublished"
    . " FROM item as i"
    . " JOIN application a ON a.id = i.application_id"
    . " group by i.application_id";

$db->setQuery($query);

$apps= $db->loadObjectList();

}

$apps = volaco();
?>

    <table >
        <?php if (count($apps)) : foreach ($apps as $app) : ?>
            <tr >
                <td  width="40%"><?php echo $app->name; ?></td>
                <td  width="20%" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $app->all_items;?></td>
                <td  width="20%" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $app->published; ?></td>
                <td  width="20%" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $app->unpublished; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    </table>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: You need to **return** your variable in the function

Comment: return results form your function then you can get it like $apps = volaco();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function `volaco()` need return type

```
return $apps= $db->loadObjectList();
```

Read [Returning values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

Add a return to your volaco() function, $apps is out of the scope.

```
function volaco ()
        {
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query = "select a.id, count(i.id) as all_items, a.name,  SUM(i.state = '1') published, SUM(i.state = '0') unpublished"
            . " FROM item as i"
            . " JOIN application a ON a.id = i.application_id"
            . " group by i.application_id";

        $db->setQuery($query);

        return $db->loadObjectList();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function volaco ()
{
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query = "select a.id, count(i.id) as all_items, a.name,  SUM(i.state = '1') published, SUM(i.state = '0') unpublished"
    . " FROM item as i"
    . " JOIN application a ON a.id = i.application_id"
    . " group by i.application_id";

$db->setQuery($query);

$apps= $db->loadObjectList();
return $apps; 

}

$apps = volaco();
?>

    <table >
        <?php if (count($apps)) : foreach ($apps as $app) : ?>
            <tr >
                <td  width="40%"><?php echo $app->name; ?></td>
                <td  width="20%" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $app->all_items;?></td>
                <td  width="20%" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $app->published; ?></td>
                <td  width="20%" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $app->unpublished; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    </table>
```